# Styling input label to align inside input box to float right

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to align my input label inside the input box and float right

The input boxes are extended from b4.

Here is what it looks like now (arrow showing what I want to do)
[image: example of what I have done]
Here is the layout (It's in vue but just ignore. Only showing for how I am arranging my elements.

```
    <label class="input-label" :for="index" v-if="showLabel">{{ label }}

        <span v-if="icon" :class="icon"></span>

        <input v-if="form !== false"
                type="text"
                v-validate="validation"
                v-model="current"
                :id="index"
                :name="index"
               :disabled="disabled"
                :placeholder="label"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has(index) }" @input="triggerEvent">

    </label>
```

And here is my attempt at css:

```
f.input-icon {
    position: relative;
}
.input-icon input {
    text-indent: 30px;
}
.input-icon span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.input-label {
    color: blue;
}
label {
    float: right;
    width: 10em;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to add `margin-top: .5em` or something to the label style? It looks like the margin-right is being picked up.

Comment: All that is doing is pushing the input box down it seems like

Comment: Ah, maybe you must position the input relatively too, as you have put in the label. Or to simplify, just put the input outside of it (in the html).

Comment: Your have class `input-label` in your HTML, but `.input-icon` in your CSS

Comment: @RoyJ What do you mean? They are both used. You can see in the screenshot that the blue `.input-label` is being registered because in the screenshot the label is blue. `.input-icon` is for the icon. I've already got that one working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this pen, which I believe answers your question. See [Form input with right aligned label pen on CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/zyEbrz). I have included my stripped down code below for quick reference.

HTML

```
<div class="form-control">
  <label>Test</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="label">
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control {
  padding: 0.625rem;
  position: relative;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.7rem;
  right: 1.625rem;
  color: blue;
}
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: @AndrewRayner Glad I could help. I have modified my CSS to ensure the inputted text, if too long, does not overlap the blue absolute positioned label. Some fine tuning on your end would be needed for your use case.